# It was a crack of spending 30 minutes hanging out with him

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is from [a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H0bA72fjHMQ?t=3634).

> Crossing over the border brought us to our first stop, the town of
> Erick and the Sandhills Curiosity Shop. This place is famous for
> Harley who lives there and was supposedly the inspiration for *Mater*
> in the *Cars* movie series. It was a **crack** of spending 30 minutes
> hanging out with him and he is an accomplished musician as well.  Do
> note that most of his jokes are pretty off-color though if you’re
> bringing your family.
>
> “Well, Hi. We want to welcome you to Erick, Oklahoma, the redneck
> capital of the world. ?????? ????? where you can see rednecks work and
> play in their own environment and sanity at its finest right here, the
> world-class, world-famous Sandhills Curiosity Shop, the only bus stop
> in town."

Is the meaning of the noun '**crack**' in bold '[moment, instant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crack)' or '[Enjoyable social activity; a good time](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/crack)'

Considering that he is an American English speaker and **'crack'** is preceded by an indefinite article, I guess that the former is more likely.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the narrator said “crack-up,” not “crack of.” In the former’s case, to “crack up” means to burst into laughter. I’m assuming that the narrator means that Harley was very funny, or that the 30 minutes spent hanging out with Harley caused the narrator to crack up.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Nah - this is definitely wrong

Comment: At least the OP here could already see that the queried usage is a ***noun***. If we're to believe your mis-hearing, the cited speaker is using a "nounified phrasal verb" immediately after an indefinite article, which seems incredibly unlikely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers “Nounified phrasal verbs” aren’t that unlikely though? In fact, they’re quite idiomatically common (“start-up,” “blackout,” “check-up,” etc.) and the speaker was obviously narrating for functionality, not for exact grammatical accuracy, so it’s very possible he extrapolated to get a point across.

Comment: But "a crack-up" doesn't have any currency with the sense of ***a very enjoyable / amusing experience***. On the other hand, "a cracker" is well established with that sense in ***all*** British dialects (not just Irish).

Answer (score 0):

The narrator is *Irish* (or "Irish-derived"). He says *It was a **cracker** spending 30 minutes with him*. As defined in [The Derry Girls Dictionary](https://www.irelandbeforeyoudie.com/the-derry-girls-dictionary-10-mad-derry-girls-phrases-explained/#:%7E:text=In%20Northern%20Ireland%2C%20when%20you,mean%20it%20is%20really%20good.)...

> *In Northern Ireland, when you say something is ‘**cracker**’, you mean it is really good.*

I'm not familiar with the *exact* usage as cited in that definition (I'd insist on an indefinite article, same as with synonymous ***a** good time*), so I don't know if it genuinely reflects current usage (for at least *some* Irish speakers; I know it's not *all*). It might just be a typo on the website.

Related Irish slang usages include *[doing something] **for the crack*** (often spelt ***craic*** to make it look more "authentically dialectal") = *for the enjoyment of it*.

This slang usage first appeared around 1972 - but so far as I'm concerned it was always as much English as Irish. As an Englishman, I was using it myself in the mid 70s, but I knew nothing of the supposedly Irish connection or the quirky spelling until several decades later. I rarely hear Americans refer to a good thing as ***a cracker***, though, so I guess it's safe to say it's a ***British*** usage. I think the work "cracker" has pejorative racist overtones to at least some Americans, so they'd probably avoid it.

Just a guess, but possibly ***the craic / crack** = **fun, enjoyment*** is connected to the much earlier usages ***crack** (**tell**) a joke, **crack** a smile, **crack up** (collapse in fits of laughter)*.

Comment: The narrator is Irish?! Where’d you get that idea from…? The accent sounds pretty American to me, Whatever he says after “crack” definitely did not end in an “r” sound, or anything like it.

Comment: Irish-American, then. Using a British/Irish expression that doesn't really have much currency in the US.

Comment: I’m sorry, but that doesn’t make a lot of sense. You’re assuming someone’s ethnic background based off of one phrase that can’t be clearly heard… there’s no evidence to support your ideation that the person is Irish-American.

Comment: @AnnabethYeung: I'm no expert when it comes to American accents, but to my ear the speaker here definitely sounds ***Irish** as well as American*. And he's unquestionably using an expression that I don't think is at all common in AmE, but is practically a *trademark* of Irish casual speech. And just listen to the way he pronounces ***famous*** (along the lines of ***fair-mus***). Perhaps the speaker is from Boston or somewhere with strong Irish influence, I dunno. And if there wasn't at least some element of "Irishness" involved, he probably wouldn't have said ***it was a cracker*** anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! I upvoted your good answer! Now, we counterbalance the downvote! Your good answer does not deserve a downvote!